# CSS white-space:nowrap

Tags: html, css

The problem is `vertical-align: top` not worked

**CSS**

```
ul { 
     width: 160px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: auto; 
    vertical-align: top;
     }
li { 
     width: 80px;
     display: inline-block;
     }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <ul>
       <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four<br />Test</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I need make one, two, three at top like four. Please help

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/

Thank you

Comment: it's not working
I need implement white-space:nowrap for slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical align your LIs instead of the UL

```
li {vertical-align:top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/88/

Answer (score 0):

This css should work...

`ul {
 
     width: 80px;
 
    display: block;
 
    /white-space: nowrap;/
 
     /overflow: auto;/
 
     }
 
li {
 
    background: papayaWhip;
 
    height: 40px;
 
     width: 80px;
 
     display: inline-block;
 
}`

Comment: That seems to have a completely different result than what the OP is looking for.